# Nowhere dense set implications

Tags: general-topology

If A is nowhere dense set.
Does it imply that $\bar{A}^c$ is dense in $\bar{A}$.

Because I have proved this and not very sure. 
If it does not happen, I will look again at my proof before posting it here to find fallacy.

This will be helpful, if someone clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

As $\bar {A}^c$ and $\bar A$ are disjoint, 
the former is the empty set within the latter.